# Mail issue - hacker or spam

Tags: windows, email

I have a web application that is hosted in the cloud. System is .net and sql, basically a portal. Some users are reporting that when they signup they are getting some spam message in Chinese. I have done everything I can think of to write outbound mails to disk and audit them as well as search the disk for the Chinese characters. Getting a bit stuck so I am wondering if there are a more "root" level of logging outbound mail. I dont know that i can install something like wireshark because it will kill resources but I should be able to somehow hook in to just mail traffic and write that out.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It's not uncommon for spammers to impersonate legit email addressed/domains in the headers of an email.

Probably good to look into the headers of the spam emails people are getting and make sure that they aren't in fact coming from your server.

While nothing can stop the spammers from using your domain name, you can make things a little harder by setting up [SPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework) well as making sure you email server isn't acting as an open mail relay.

Comment: I have been trying to get the email headers for about 2 weeks but it is my customers customer...making it a bit tough. The weird part is that the "spam" seems to occur when the user resets their password. its a heavily integrated system so we cant actually make fake users. So we are a bit stuck seeing what end users actually see. Our dev environment for sure does not have this issue